# Fetch JSON skip the unique id in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. When I retrieve data from Firebase, I found that the unique id avoids me to access data inside.

For example,

```
{
  "-LAT14AJ6_wJND4Fg-Y3" : {
    "Fat" : 12,
    "Protein" : 18,
    "calories" : 300,
    "corp" : "McDonald",
    "name" : "Egg McMuffin",
    "timestamp" : "2018-04-19 21-11-51"
  }
}
```

what I need is only

```
 {
"Fat" : 12,
"Protein" : 18,
"calories" : 300,
"corp" : "McDonald",
"name" : "Egg McMuffin",
"timestamp" : "2018-04-19 21-11-51"
}

firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/added_food/2018-04-19`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    this.setState({ foodData: snapshot.val() })
  });
```

Can I skip the unique ID on modifying the ref link? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the ID itself in the query:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/added_food/2018-04-19/-LAT14AJ6_wJND4Fg-Y3`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    this.setState({ foodData: snapshot.val() })
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, since my query is static that I cant hard code the id every time when I retrieve data.

Comment: Then you'll have to write code to dig into the snapshot that you get from the query you started with.  There's no way around this.